# File::rename() deleting the target file instead of changing it

Tags: ruby

From the current working directory I am trying to rename a file which is in another directory. My test `IRB` code is below:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\peter>irb
irb(main):001:0> Dir.pwd
=> "C:/Documents and Settings/peter"
irb(main):002:0> File.rename('C:\Documents and Settings\peter\My Documents\userdata\test.txt','a.txt')
=> 0
irb(main):003:0>File.exist?('C:\Documents and Settings\peter\My Documents\userdata\test.txt')
=> false
irb(main):004:0>File.exist?('C:\Documents and Settings\peter\My Documents\userdata\a.txt')
=> false
irb(main):005:0>
```

Instead of renaming the target file is getting deleted from the file system - why so? If it is not the right approach to rename a file, please advice me a safe approach. But I can't change the current working directory for renaming, and to rename if I need to change the current directory,after renaming I want to get back the previous current working directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should not use backslashes here. The reason for this is that backslash is an escape sequence initiator, so you might get very unexpected results next time (if you accidentally use backslashes in a double-quoted string, for example). In this case there were no problems, but it's a dumb luck. Always use forward slashes in file paths. [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) on [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) should handle them just fine.

Second, you're looking in the wrong place. Renamed file should appear at

```
C:/Documents and Settings/peter/a.txt
```

Because this is your current working dir. If you want it to appear in "C:/Documents and Settings/peter/My Documents/userdata" either change the working dir before renaming, or specify a full target file path.

```
File.rename('C:/Documents and Settings/peter/My Documents/userdata/test.txt',
            'C:/Documents and Settings/peter/My Documents/userdata/a.txt')
```

You can also use a block with [Dir::chdir](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-chdir).

```
Dir.chdir('C:/Documents and Settings/peter/My Documents/userdata') do
  File.rename('test.txt', 'a.txt')
end
```

After block returns, working dir is restored to whatever it was before `chdir` call.

Comment: I am using `Windows XP`. And all my scripts I used this `\\`. There was no problem.

Comment: I still encourage you to use forward slashes. Next time you use backslashes in a double-quoted string and - bam! - you have a problem.

Comment: No the `test.txt` is in the `userdata` folder, and I have to change it there. But I have tried, that if I change the current working directory to the `userdata`, then renaming occurs perfectly.

Comment: Yes, either specify full file path for target file, or change working dir like that.

Comment: If I use `block` then any idea how I then get back to the previous current directory? Your idea is very nice,If a bit help you give,I can give it a good start.

Comment: Yeah! I am just saying if you provide me a sample of that, with my example. Then I can use that idea to my actual implementation.